# kivy buildozer failing to patch file setup.py

Tags: python, android, kivy, patch, buildozer

I'm trying to debug and deploy my kivy application using Buildozer and I'm getting this error.
the command I use is :

```
buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

and this is the error I get.

```
RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /home/kamel/diagnostic_automobilekv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/Pillow/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/Pillow -p1 -i /home/kamel/diagnostic_automobilekv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/Pillow/patches/fix-setup.patch

  STDOUT:
patching file setup.py
Hunk #2 succeeded at 318 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 567.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 647.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 727 with fuzz 2 (offset 10 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 783 (offset 14 lines).
2 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej


  STDERR:

Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=diagnostic --bootstrap=sdl2 --
requirements=python3==3.7.1,Kivy==1.11.1,setuptools,certifi==2020.6.20,chardet==3.0.4,docutils==0.16,
idna==2.10,isodate==0.6.0,kivy-deps.glew==0.2.0,kivy-deps.gstreamer==0.2.0,kivy-deps.sdl2==0.2.0,
Kivy-garden==0.1.4,kivymd==0.104.1,Pillow==7.2.0,Pygments==2.6.1,pyparsing==2.4.7,pypiwin32==223,
pywin32==228,rdflib==5.0.0,requests==2.24.0,six==1.15.0,urllib3==1.25.10 --arch armeabi-v7a
 --copy-libs --color=always
 --storage-dir="/home/kamel/diagnostic_automobilekv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by removing pillow from the requirements in the buildozer.spec file